# Block websites with /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, internet

So I tried blocking some websites for obvious reasons but I can still keep going to these sites even when I 'supposedly' blocked them.

I've edited the `/etc/hosts` file so it looks like this (example being Facebook)

```
0.0.0.0       https://www.facebook.com
0.0.0.0       facebook.com
0.0.0.0       www.facebook.com
```

Yet I can still access Facebook. What am I doing wrong?

> **EDIT: Only Chrome seems to block out the website, though I can still
>   access it trough Safari and Firefox.**

I'm running OS X Yosemite

Comment: @Steven Still possible to acces the website

Comment: @Steven 0.0.0.0 is not same as 127.0.0.1, change it to 127.0.0.1 and see if it works

Comment: @Steven Still possible, I wanted to use 0.0.0.0 so I didn't have to wait for the timeout. The question is towards unix systems.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a better option than 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Steven I've updated the OP. Not a duplicate since it listens to the file, only in Chrome. I also have other sites in there that I need to disable to access certain files when not at work and re-enable them at work. That works.

Comment: Side note: Why  `facebook.com` which includes everything ending on facebook.com AND  www.facebook.com ?

Comment: @Hennes Was just covering all possibilities

Comment: @RandomPerson do you use a proxy server?

Answer (score 10):

Use the following instead:

```
127.0.0.1      facebook.com
127.0.0.1      www.facebook.com
```

The IP address 127.0.0.1 is the [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), aka local loopback, address for your system. By using 127.0.0.1, you are telling your system that facebook.com's IP address is the address of your system itself, effectively making FaceBook unreachable, since the system will get the IP address for the site from the hosts file rather than performing a [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) lookup. The first entry you put in the file, https://www.facebook.com, doesn't belong there. The file provides a static mechanism for translating a [fully qualified domain name (FQDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) to an IP address, so should only contain FQDNs or host names with associated IP addresses, not those prefixed by a protocol, such as HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc.

Comment: I've tried this before but it only works when using Chrome. If I tried to access the website with Firefox or Safari I would still be able to reach it

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is nonsensical and inferior to 0.0.0.0

Comment: @RandomPerson, [Firefox has its own DNS cache](http://ccm.net/faq/555-disabling-the-dns-cache-in-mozilla-firefox). Clear the Firefox cache and try again. Safari may also be using a cached DNS entry. Rebooting would likely clear any cached entries.

Comment: @moonpoint Rebooted and cleared cache. Both still have access to the website

Comment: @RandomPerson, what do you see if you ping facebook.com from within a Terminal window? You mentioned you are using Yosemite; when I added an entry to /etc/hosts on an OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) system, access was blocked. But there is a report of a similar problem on the Apple StackExchange site by someone running Yosemite at [OS X 10.10.1 /etc/hosts & /private/etc/hosts file is being ignored and not resolving](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158117/os-x-10-10-1-etc-hosts-private-etc-hosts-file-is-being-ignored-and-not-resol) - see JB Smith's fix for blocking Facebook there.